# How to delete existing project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I am new to eclipse. That above problem I face when I wanted to import existing project. Actually first time when I imported the same project I forgot to check "copy project in workspace" and when I came to know about it I tried to re-import it but it said like project already exist. I could have delete that project in order to re-import it but I found it nowhere in my workspace(don't know why). I researched the same on internet but found nothing.

**But suddenly one idea stuck in my mind and it worked also.**
Create another workspace and import that project in that workspace again, It will work. LOL :)

Comment: or rename either the new or existing project?

Answer (score 1):

Delete the project details from the following location.

```
/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

**To delete a project and remove its contents from    the file system:**

- Select the project in one of the navigation views.
- Click Delete on       the pop-up menu.     In the dialog which opens
  select Also    delete     contents under ....
- Click Yes.

  **To delete a project from the
  workspace    without removing its contents from the file system:**
- Select the project in one of the navigation views.
- Click Delete on      the pop-up menu.
- In the dialog which opens select **Do not delete contents**
- Click Yes.